# How can a change data based off of user's location?

Tags: ios, swift, location

I created a tableview with 2 cells, with each cell showing both your senators (based off of your location). I used CLGeocoder to successfully grab the user's zipcode, and I then put that value (which is of type string) into a variable that declared outside of the function.

Ideally, I want to go to a different function in the class, and use that string variable (which should hold the user's zip code) to create specific data. However, it doesn't work!

Here is the code that extracts the zip code and puts it in var zipCode:(note that the print function in the if condition successfully prints the zip code in the terminal when I run the program).

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

var zipcode: String = ""

func getTableInfo() {

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(locationManager.location!, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error!.localizedDescription)

        }

        if placemarks!.count > 0 {
            let pm = placemarks![0]

            self.zipcode = pm.postalCode!

            print(self.zipcode)
        }

        else {
            print("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
        }
    })

}
```

I call this function in `viewDidLoad()` and then in the `viewDidLoad()` function, using an if-statement, I try to use the zip code to change an array of strings. `names[]` is declared as a empty array of strings right above the `viewDidLoad()` function.

```
    if zipcode == "94108" {
        names[1] = "WORKS!"
        print(names)
    }
```

For some reason, it doesn't print the names! (Note that the zip code is indeed 94108 because 94108 is what prints in the console when I ask to print 'zipcode')

Comment: Where are you executing your `if zipcode == "94108` statement? Are you sure the CLGeocoder function is finished yet?

Comment: It successfully works when put within the CLGeocoder() function, but the issue is that when I print names[] later on in my program, names[1] doesn't include the updated element.

Comment: Right - but `reverseGeocode` is an async function, so there is a slight delay in the execution.  If you put your if statement immediately after your `reverseGeocode` func it'll almost certainly still be "" since `reverseGeocode` is still running.  See the other answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a completion handler for your getTableInfo method, like this:

```
typealias ZipcodeCompletionBlock = (String?) -> Void

func getTableInfo(completionBlock: @escaping ZipcodeCompletionBlock) {

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(locationManager.location!, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error!.localizedDescription)
            completionBlock(nil)
        } else if placemarks!.count > 0 {
            let pm = placemarks![0]
            self.zipcode = pm.postalCode!
            completionBlock(self.zipcode)
        } else {
            print("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
            completionBlock(nil)
        }
    })

}
```

Now you can call this function like this inside viewDidLoad:

```
self.getTableInfo { zipcode in
    if zipcode == "94108" {
        self.names[1] = "WORKS!"
        print(self.names)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of a slight delay in the execution of the code that saves the ZIP code, so zipcode is still "" when your print code is run. Completion handlers are in place because they execute code AFTER the function is done. Put the following code right after print(self.zipcode)

```
if zipcode == "94108" {
    names[1] = "WORKS!"
    print(names)
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: So now names[] successfully prints the new output on the console, but why does that only work within the getTableInfo()? How can I make it so that it prints successfully in different functions?

Comment: I would call those functions from inside of the completion block, that is the only way to know for sure that your zipcode has been successfully set.